# PostgreSQL - Create view with autoincremental column

Tags: postgresql, view, postgresql-9.2

I have a PostgreSQL table, and I need to create a view with a new column. This column needs to be an auto-incremental column starting at 1 and going to N.

Is this possible to do without effecting the original schema of the legacy data structure?

Comment: You can use `row_number OVER ()` (a window function) for this, if I understand it correctly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As @deszo said user OVER()

```
create view foo as (
    select row_number() over (order by field), field, field2, field3 from bar
)
```

Comment: This creates a field as a bigint, How can I create the field as a long int?  I need a 32bit ID field.

Comment: You can cast the row_number to integer when selecting columns from the view

Comment: You cast by doing <field>::<type>.  Thank for all your help everyone!

Comment: Placement of cast operator can be tricky with window functions: `row_number() over (order by field)::int`

Answer (score 21):

You can use row_number, and the easiest way is to just add a

```
row_number() OVER ()
```

field into the view. You need the PARTITION BY and using the "true" expression is the most performant way (no need for sorting like in Fabrizio Mazzoni's answer).

Update: Also no need to partition by true, just use () as the "over" expression.

Comment: Thanks for saving me another google search. For others' reference, if you need to cast it to a certain type like the OP, you can wrap the whole thing in parentheses and select your type. Ex: `(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TRUE))::int4`